# Firewall with NAT, Do I Need A Router?

Tags: networking, router, lan, nat, juniper

I have a home lab that is behind a Juniper NS-50 firewall. I can reach the firewall's admin page from a laptop (on the trusted LAN), but I can't get the servers within the (trusted) lab to communicate to each other. I'm wondering if I need a router within the trust zone of the firewall in addition to the home router that the untrust zone connects to.

The firewall is set to route mode running NAT services.

From the users guide:

> In Route mode, the NetScreen-50 device operates at Layer 3. Because you can configure
>   each interface using an IP address and subnet mask, you can configure individual
>   interfaces to perform NAT.
>
> - When the interface performs NAT services, the device translates the source IP
>     address of each outgoing packet into the IP address of the untrusted port. It also
>     replaces the source port number with a randomly-generated value.

My confusion is that I have a laptop I'm using can connect to the firewall's website. It can also access the internet, servers, and iDrac, but the servers can't ping each other. So do I need an additional router on the inside?

Comment: Are the servers on the same private subnet? Are you trying to have them ping each others' private IP addresses, or are you trying to have them ping each other based on their public DNS names, which may be resolving to the public IP address of the NAT? If it's the latter, you might need to enable NAT Loopback (a.k.a. NAT hairpinning) on your NAT.

Comment: Hey @Spiff, thanks for your response. Yes to the same private subnet and using IPs. The rest I'm going to have to look into. Thanks for giving me some stuff to look into!